# Why would an Insert statement always fire no matter the results of the preceeding IF statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using a SQL Server 2005 database, and I have an If statement that is behaving in two different manners against the same data set, depending on the actions to be taken in the begin...end block.

First, if I merely want to print to the console, the following code prints nothing, as expected:

```
if (not exists(select null from tblControls where Name = 'SOME_CONTROL_NAME'))
begin
  print 'control not found'
end
```

Whereas this code prints 'control found' as expected:

```
if (exists(select null from tblControls where Name = 'SOME_CONTROL_NAME'))
begin
  print 'control found'
end
```

However, if I change the code to this:

```
if (not exists(select null from tblControls where Name = 'SOME_CONTROL_NAME'))
begin
  insert into tblControls values (632, 'NEW_CONTROL_NAME', 'New Control', 1, 1, NULL, 1, 'DataControls.CheckBox', NULL, NULL, 1) 
end
```

The insert statement ALWAYS fires, even though a matching record exists in tblControls.   Is there something special about insert statements in T-SQL 2005 that could be causing this behavior, or am I missing something obvious?  I would understand if the logic of the code is wrong, but when I tested using the print statement it works as expected.

EDIT:  Its generating an "Insert Error" message.

Any help with this frustrating problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the NULL in the Exists..Select that's confusing it. Try:

```
if (not exists(select * from tblControls where Name = 'SOME_CONTROL_NAME'))
begin
  insert into tblControls values (632, 'NEW_CONTROL_NAME', 'New Control', 1, 1, NULL, 1, 'DataControls.CheckBox', NULL, NULL, 1) 
end
```

Also, it can be rewritten without the parentheses and Begin/End:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblControls WHERE Name = 'SOME_CONTROL_NAME') 
  INSERT INTO tblControls VALUES (632, 'NEW_CONTROL_NAME', 'New Control', 1, 1, NULL, 1, 'DataControls.CheckBox', NULL, NULL, 1)
```

Comment: That's the first thing I thought of, too!  Unfortunately, I tried changing it to * but it didn't solve anything. Plus, the fact that the print statements work as expected tells me its something else.  begin...end is part of our coding standard for if statements so I can't remove that.

Comment: @WilliamSmith - What result do you get if you execute the statement `SELECT * FROM tblControls WHERE Name = 'SOME_CONTROL_NAME'` ?

Comment: @WilliamSmith,  Try using the second solution (with the Begin/End).  I always use it and it has never failed.  Also, is the number of VALUEs in the INSERT statement the same as the number of (non-Identity) columns in tblControls?

Comment: Try it on sqlfiddle.com, I will put a fiddle up when the wife comes off the pc!

Comment: @Lieven - Basically the same result, except it returns the row data now.

Comment: @Holger Brandt - Removing Begin / End had the same effect....however, I did take a second look at the table itself based on your comment.  I was off by 1 column- I needed to add another NULL to my list of values.  When I added the NULL, the error went away!  So apparently SQL Server will VALIDATE a statement, even if it is not going to execute that statement- does that sound right?  Frustrating for me here, but I can see the value if that's really the case.

Comment: @WilliamSmith Yes, that is correct.  SQL Server will validate each statement before actually executing the code, even if the **result** of the SQL will skip that branch of the code.